# How to find Latin characters in a table?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a table which has first name and last name in oracle

There are some name which has Latin characters in it. I have written a query to find out them but it shows no results . Please see if I am right

```
select first_name, second_name from customer_table where 
length(asciistr(first_name))!=length(first_name)
```

Please advice

UPDATE :

My data was corrupt and now the same query works.

I have another question with same

Is there is any way to save Latin E with Ascii e while saving in DB ?

Comment: Does your database characterset supports Latin?

Comment: I checked it says UTF8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle has an utility for this purpose. `csscan`.

See [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch12scanner.htm)

Comment: Thanks . my query worked . Is there is any way to save the data in ASCII ?

Comment: `Select * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`. If it tells you that the database uses internally US7ASCII, then probably there is no way. Except from using NVARCHAR2, or convert the database into AL32UTF8.

Comment: it says UTF8 . Then how come it accepts the Latin E ?

Comment: You also have to set NLS_LANG (and character set) on client side.